# How to change the icon when selecting tab and make the main tab that is in the middle?

Tags: flutter

I'm starting to study flutter and tried to make a simple tabbar. Also enabled the package "material_design_icons_flutter". I need regular and outline icons in it. How do I make sure that when tab was not selected, there was one icon, and when selected, the icon changed to another? And how else can I make sure that when the app starts, the main tab is for example the one in the middle?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:material_design_icons_flutter/material_design_icons_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(TabLayoutDemo());

class TabLayoutDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(MdiIcons.homeOutline),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              )
            ],
            labelColor: Colors.blue,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black45,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
//            indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TabBar is supposed to be used at the top and BottomNavigationBar at the bottom. You should use a BottomNavigationBar instead.

Set your scaffold like this:

```
            Scaffold(
              bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                currentIndex: currentTab, //variable declared at top
                items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
                      activeIcon:
                          Icon(Icons.grade) //Set to the icon when selected
                      ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(MdiIcons.homeOutline),
                      activeIcon:
                          Icon(Icons.grade) //Set to the icon when selected
                      ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                      activeIcon:
                          Icon(Icons.grade) //Set to the icon when selected
                      ),
                ],
                onTap: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    currentTab = index;
                    currentPage = pages[index];
                  });
                },
              ),
              body: currentPage,
            ),
```

Declare the variables outside of build function:

```
  int currentTab = 1; //Choose the index of the home tab
  List<Widget> pages;
  Widget currentPage;
```

Set the value of variables inside init function

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    pages = [
      Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.orange,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.lightGreen,
      ),
    ];
    currentPage = pages[currentTab];

    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: I dont think BottomNavigationBar has a swipe function. You could try to wrap all the containers with gesture detector and add a function for swipe.